# Apply id's to td elements that are not in the html code

Tags: jquery, html, string, html-table

I'm trying to parse a table that's not in my html file, I get a whole HTML file from a string and then I put it in a div of my own.

I've been able to modify it with CSS, but either jQuery or Javascript seem to be able to play with the table inside.

I get the content like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $.get("untouchable-url-on-my-host",function(data,status){       
        $("#content").html(data);   
    });
});
```

My div content always appears in the font code like this:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

This generates a huge table on the div and I would like to parse its contents.

What I thought was to parse the original string in order to replace text:

```
'td class'
```

to

```
'td id="number" class'
```

But i do need a loop that does the non-repeating-same-ids trick and i'm not able to do it.

Any idea?

Comment: please clarify what 'class' is in your replacement text

Answer (score 1):

You can make the HTML string into a jquery object like so:

```
var jqueryObject = $(data);
```

With this object you can for instance alter the td's. Here is an example of how you would alter a td with a class="class" attribute and setting that element to have an id="number":

```
jqueryObject.find('td.class').attr('id', 'number');
```

Once you are done with any modification to your HTML you can just add the jquery object into your DOM like so:

```
$('#content').append(jqueryObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried but does not work, i get the same result, it just don't replace any text

Comment: This code is assuming that you are using 'class' as a class, if you  want to change all the td's to have id=number then you have to alter the 'td.class'-string to only 'td'

Answer (score 0):

I have used this as a test purpose:

```
            var temp = '<table><tr><td class="yourclass">sdfdf</td><td class="yourclass">sds</td></tr></table>';

             var occurence_count = temp.match(/td class/g).length;
             for(i = 1; i<=occurence_count; i++){
                            temp = temp.replace(new RegExp('td class', ''), 'td id="my_cusom_id-' + i+'" class');
            }

            console.log(temp);
```

And it display the result as it should.
And in my case I got occurence_count = 2

Or you can use the solution which is posted as an answer in a modified way

```
            $.get("untouchable-url-on-my-host",function(data,status){ 
             var $data = $(data);
            $data.find('td').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', 'my_custom_id_'+ $(this).index());
            $("#content").append($data);
            });
            }
```

You can try this solutions

```
            $.get("untouchable-url-on-my-host",function(data,status){       
            var temp = data;
            var occurence_count = temp.match(/td class/g).length;
            for(i = 1; i<=occurence_count; i++){
               temp = temp.replace(new RegExp('td class', ''), 'td id="my_custom_id-' + i+'" class');
            }
              $("#content").html(temp);   

            }); });
```

Comment: Just tried, same result, it does not replace any one.

Comment: Can you post the html for a single td..That will help to understand the pattern

Comment: Hi Abhisek, yes with this new one it does 1 replacement at least. How many "occurence_count" do you get? It gives me just 1, however there are about 30 "td class" in the string.

Comment: I've tried to do the loop till 30 but it just seems to replace all the time the same line.

Comment: If your every td must contain the same class then the above code should work.

Comment: Yes with your "temp" it gives me 2 occurence_count, with mine it still gives me one. Anyway it still replace just the first line when i do a 30 loop :/

Comment: you can use the approach @Adrian Foursis. I have edited my solution with his approach.

Answer (score 0):

**OK it worked**, here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$.get("untouchable-url-of-my-host",function(data,status){          

     var $data = $(data);
        $data.find('td').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', 'my_custom_id_'+ $(this).index());
        $("#content").append($data);


      });            
});
});
```

Here's the result:

```
<table class="status" width="100%" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td id="my_custom_id_0" class="statusEven">
<td id="my_custom_id_1" class="status">
<td id="my_custom_id_2" class="status">CRITICAL</td>
<td id="my_custom_id_3" class="status" nowrap="">07-10-2014 12:46:34</td>
<td id="my_custom_id_4" class="status" nowrap=""> 0d 2h 19m 42s</td>
<td id="my_custom_id_5" class="status">3/3</td>
<td id="my_custom_id_6" class="status" valign="center"> </td>
...
```

The only thing is that the IDs are repeating in every TR from 0 to 6 again xD but i'll figure it out.

THANKS!!!!